# How do I prevent new sections in a word document from using the background image and styling from the title page?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a document derived from a template in MS Word 2007 I inherited from a predecessor in my company and am having some difficulty making it behave.

The first page of the document includes a fancy image and a load of special formatting which doesn't appear later in the document.

When I create a new section in the document (so that I can make a portion of the document appear in landscape), that new section starts with the image from the title page. I'd like it to just look like another plain page in the document.

So my question is how do I prevent the first page in a new section from acquiring the background image and styling found on the first section in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Create a new section (Page layout > Breaks > New section).
2. Change to landscape (Page Layout > 'More'button > Landscape && Apply to: This section).
3. Double-click on the header area to open the 'Header & Footer Tools'.
4. Click on the header area at the top of the page.
5. Un-select 'Header & Footer Tools' > Design > Different First Page.